# How to add extra attributes to queryset in django rest api using serialiser and listViewAPI?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, serialization

How do I add additional fields like count, status_code to the queryset in the django rest api?

```
class SongList(generics.ListAPIView):
"""
API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited===1111.
"""
serializer_class = SongSerialier
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Song.objects.all()
    id = self.request.query_params.get('id', None)
    test=QuerySet()

    return queryset
```

Above code returns only the content in the `SongSerialier` in the form of list, for example

```
[
    {
        "song_title": "song1",
        "file_type": "mp3",
        "album": 1,
        "test": "1",
        "my_field": false
    },
    {
        "song_title": "song1",
        "file_type": "mp3",
        "album": 2,
        "test": "1",
        "my_field": false
    }
]
```

I want my output like below format

```
{
status_code:200,
count:2,
total_count:4,
data:[
    {
        "song_title": "song1",
        "file_type": "mp3",
        "album": 1,
        "test": "1",
        "my_field": false
    },
    {
        "song_title": "song1",
        "file_type": "mp3",
        "album": 2,
        "test": "1",
        "my_field": false
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Please add your serializer code. You can add easily addional fields in your serializer.

Comment: restframework add automatically status code and if you need count then use Pagination then u get count [Pagination](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/). total_count means total_count when you use filter queryset or just all records in your songs table?

Answer (score 0):

*following is my serializer code*

```
class SongSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):   
    test=serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    my_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField('is_named_bar')

    def is_named_bar(self, foo):
        return foo.id == "bar"
    def get_test(self, obj):
        print ("OBJ, ",obj,type(obj),obj.id)
        return "1"
    class Meta:
        model=Song
        fields=('song_title','file_type','album','test','my_field')
```

Answer (score 0):

> GOT THE SOLUTION
>   *You need to override the list method in the ListAPIView *

```
class SongList(generics.ListAPIView):
i=0
"""
API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited===1111.


"""
serializer_class = SongSerialier


def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super(SongList, self).list(request, args, kwargs)
    # Add data to response.data Example for your object:
    print("Data    ::: ",type(response),response,response.data)#,dict(response.data))
    print ("datat  type: ",type(response.data))
    d1 = collections.OrderedDict()
    d1['a'] = 'A'
    d1['b'] = 'B'
    d1['c'] = 'C'
    d1['d'] = 'D'
    d1['e'] = 'E'
    response.data=d1
    self.no+=1
    print ("no:2  ",self.no)
    # response.data["a_status_code"]=200
    # response.data["a_status_text"] = "Success"
    #response['10_mi_count'] = 10
    # a=response.render().content
    # print ("a: ",a)
    return response
def get_queryset(self):
    self.no=1
    print ("no:1 ",self.no)
    queryset = Song.objects.all().annotate(count_test=Count('id'))
    id = self.request.query_params.get('id', None)
    test=QuerySet()
    #print( "=========111" ,type(queryset),self.serializer_class.data)
    # print ("j1: ",j)
    # j+=1
    return queryset
```

> This will give the result as

[Check link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GcYt.png)

Comment: Here I have completely changed to output response by sending static collection dictionary